# Tomcat não exibe páginas jsp no servidor de produção

Tags: tomcat, jsp, deploy

Estou usando o `Tomcat 8` em minha aplicação, quando eu gero o `.war` para fazer o deploy ele aparentemente faz tudo certinho.

Porém, quando vou acessar a pagina /index.jsp está dando **erro 404.**

Quando vou verificar os arquivos no servidor, estão todos lá, todos os JSPs.

O que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: já tentou verificar a pasta web apps do tomcat e ver, se o seu .war está de fato lá? e qual o nome que foi gerado nesse .war, pois esse sera o contexto de acesso a sua pagina.

Comment: Complementando o que o colega disse e adicionado uma informação, dentro da pasta `webapps`, deve ter a pasta descompactada do seu projeto e o arquivo `war` que vc gero, vc tb pode dar uma olhada no arquivo `catalina.out` que fica na pasta `logs`.

Answer (score 0):

Para entrar no index.jsp, deixe ele somente dentro da pasta WebContent e não dentro da WebContent/WEB-INF .

Assim como no Exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]